# The Android photo picker library does not open the gallery on Android 11 and 12

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11, android-12, android-photo-picker

I have implemented the Android photo picker library as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker), but on Android devices running Android 11 and 12 (API 30 and 31), the library automatically invokes the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent action rather than the gallery.

The code:

```
private lateinit var pickMultipleMediaLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest>
```

Registers the photo picker activity launcher in multi-select mode.

```
private fun registerPhotoPicker() {
        pickMultipleMediaLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(PickMultipleVisualMedia(imageSelectionLimitCount)) { uris ->
                uris.forEach {
                        getRealPathFromMediaURI(it)?.let { imagePath -> imagesPath.add(imagePath) }
                }
            }
    }
```

Launch the photo picker

```
pickMultipleMediaLauncher.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder().build())
```

Get the real path from media URI

```
fun getRealPathFromMediaURI(uri: Uri): String? {
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
        val columnIndex = cursor?.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)

        return try {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                val filePath = columnIndex?.let { cursor.getString(it) }
                cursor.close()
                filePath
            } else null
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this function deliver a 'real path' if the content scheme uri is is like content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000464640 ?

Comment: for "content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000037" uri the function delivers "/sdcard/.transforms/synthetic/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000037.jpg"

Comment: Yes, i see that here too. Pretty amazing as you will not have placed the file there. It looks like a copy. It is not the 'real' path. But why is this done in this way? Found that File.exists() and File.canRead() both returned true. The .transform directory is not to be found further.

Comment: Although it is not the 'real' path, the result is acceptable and meets my needs.
My problem is when I try to select photos, the photo picker library on Android 11 and 12 launches 'my file' rather than the gallery, but it functions properly on Android 13.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation, from [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#add-dependency) section, you can find a small paragraph explaining when and why the Intent `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is automatically called.

> **If the photo picker isn't available on a device, the library automatically invokes the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent action instead**. This intent is supported on devices that run Android 4.4 (API level 19) or higher. You can verify whether the photo picker is available on a given device by calling isPhotoPickerAvailable().

Scrolling down the documentation to the section [Device Availability](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#device-availability) will provide you a more detailed explanation and how to possibly solve your problem:

> The photo picker is available on devices that meet the following criteria:
>
> - Run Android 11 (API level 30) or higher
> - Receive changes to Modular System Components through Google System Updates
>
> Older devices that run Android 4.4 (API level 19) through Android 10 (API level 29) and Android Go devices running Android 11 or 12 that support Google Play services can install a backported version of the photo picker.